# switch REST\json httpclient4.2 to normal HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, json, http, rest, httpclient

I have a java 6 client sending REST\json request with apache httpclient4.2 .

I want to convert all my rest calls to use java 6  HTTPURLConnection
(or net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpURLConnection), for security reasons.

how do I do that?

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the security reasons are?

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is how to use `OutputStreamWriter` and `InputStreamReader`. Here is an example: https://github.com/Hypertopic/Porphyry/blob/master/src/org/hypertopic/RESTDatabase.java#L181